# JavaScript BigInt print unsigned binary represenation

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bigint

How do you print an unsigned integer when using JavaScript's `BigInt`?

`BigInt`s can be printed as binary representation using `toString(2)`. However for negative values this function just appends a `-` sign when printing.

```
BigInt(42).toString(2)
// output => 101010
BigInt(-42).toString(2)
// output => -101010
```

How do I print the unsigned representation of `BigInt(42)`? I that with regular `number`s you can do `(-42 >>> 0).toString(2)`, however the unsigned right shift seems not to be implemented for `BigInt`, resulting in an error

```
(BigInt(-42) >>> BigInt(0)).toString(2)
// TypeError: BigInts have no unsigned right shift, use >> instead
```

Comment: To solve the TypeError you need to wrap 0 in BigInt as well. However BigInts have no unsigned right shift since BigInt has no definitive length.

Comment: Right sorry but this gives another error message. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Since negative BigInts are represented as infinite-length two's complement, you cannot convert them to binary - you need to either convert them to a fixed-length values like number or write a custom function that will convert them based on the current length.

Comment: Got it seems logical. So I know that my numbers are always 64-bit unsigned integers, how would I then do it?

Comment: Since JS numbers are 64-bit doubles, you may need to write a custom class to handle it based on BigInt. You can also just write a function that'll convert a BigInt number to it's binary representation by considering every BigInt as 64-bit values.

Comment: Could you give some advice on implementing a custom print function? Is there something like `bitAtIndex` for `BigInt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get the two's complement representation for negative BigInts is to use `BigInt.asUintN(bit_width, bigint)`:

```
> BigInt.asUintN(64, -42n).toString(2)
'1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010110'
```

Note that:

- You have to define the number of bits you want (64 in my example), there is no "natural"/automatic value for that.
- Given only that string of binary digits, there is no way to tell whether this is meant to be a positive BigInt (with a value close to 2n**64n) or a two's complement representation of -42n. So if you want to reverse the conversion later, you'll have to provide this information somehow (e.g. by writing your code such that it implicitly assumes one or the other option).
- Relatedly, this is not how `-42n` is stored internally in current browsers. (But that doesn't need to worry you, since you can create this output whenever you want/need to.)
- You could achieve the same result with a subtraction: `((2n ** 64n) - 42n).toString(2)` -- again, you can specify how many bits you'd like to see.

> Is there something like `bitAtIndex` for `BigInt`?

No, because there is no specification for how BigInts are represented. Engines can choose to use bits in any way they want, as long as the resulting BigInts behave as the specification demands.

---

@Kyroath:

> negative BigInts are represented as infinite-length two's complement

No, they are not: the implementations in current browsers represent BigInts as "sign + magnitude", not as two's complement. However, this is an unobservable implementation detail: implementations could change how they store BigInts internally, and BigInts would behave just the same.

What you probably meant to say is that the two's complement representation of any negative integer (big or not) is conceptually an infinite stream of 1-bits, so printing or storing that in finite space always requires defining a number of characters/bits after which the stream is simply cut off. When you have a fixed-width type, that obviously defines this cutoff point; for conceptually-unlimited BigInts, you have to define it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to convert 64-bit BigInts into binary strings:

```js
// take two's complement of a binary string
const twosComplement = (binaryString) => {
  let complement = BigInt('0b' + binaryString.split('').map(e => e === "0" ? "1" : "0").join(''));
  return decToBinary(complement + BigInt(1));
}

const decToBinary = (num) => {
  let result = ""

  const isNegative = num < 0;
  if (isNegative) num = -num;

  while (num > 0) {
    result = (num % BigInt(2)) + result;
    num /= BigInt(2);
  }

  if (result.length > 64) result = result.substring(result.length - 64);
  result = result.padStart(64, "0");

  if (isNegative) result = twosComplement(result);
  return result;
}

console.log(decToBinary(BigInt(5))); // 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101
console.log(decToBinary(BigInt(-5))); // 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011
```

This code doesn't do any validation, however.